# Payara HttpServletResponse.sendError() not sending reason to browser, only status code

Tags: exception, http-status-code-400, payara

### Update 4

- **Before reading this question**, be aware: this question is **wrong**, based on false premises.
- The problem described does not exist.
- I was getting more and more confused with the situation, so I wrote a Java app that uses raw Socket (HTTP 1.1 and HTTPS 1.1) to connect to the servers in question. In that raw access, the servers ALWAYS returned the expected message. So the problem lies with Chrome or Payara using the `h2` protocol.
- The real problem lies somewhere in the way that Chrome or Payara handle HTTP exception codes via SSL on the protocol `h2` (HTTP/2). (I will remodel my app to also check h2 requests, to find out if it's Java or Payara or Chrome that cause the problem)
- - When NOT using SSL, the error code and message get passed properly (because Chrome falls back to `HTTP/1.1`, where the message gets passed along)
- - When using SSL, Chrome only displays the (numerical) error code, while the error message gets lost. (I do not know yet if it's a Chrome/Payara implementation problem, or if HTTP/2 might not support textual error mossages besides the numerical status error codes)

### Background

I'm using Payara server to host some apps.
On my DEV server I'm using

> 5.201 #badassfish (build 512) (Community)

and on the PROD server I'm running

> Payara Server Enterprise 5.31.0 #badassfish (build 4356)

### Problem

When running the following code in an HttpServlet

```
@Override protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest pReq, final HttpServletResponse pResp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    pReq.sendError(400, "LDAP credentials invalid!");
}
```

then my Dev server returns HTTP status code

> 400 LDAP credentials invalid!

while PROD only returns

> 400

with the actual message `LDAP credentials invalid!` missing.

### Question

Is there any setting I can tweak in a config file or the code so that my Payara PROD actually passes the message along properly?

- Properly sending the 1st HTTP response line `HTTP/1.1 400 LDAP credentials invalid!`,
- instead of just `HTTP/1.1 400`)

### Notes

- The client is a thin client, only grabbing the status code and displaying it to the user, when a 4xx code comes back from the server.
- I'm using the code 400 and specific messages because any error at that point shall cause the same reaction by the frontend (to NOT log in the user), but to show that different message(s, actually there's lots of different cases) to the user.
- Working out a full catalogue of 4xx error codes with the frontend devs is something I'd rather not do at this point yet. Unless I'm really stuck with that problems and using different codes.
- Same goes for writing a wrapper JSON response (actually containing the error message).

### Update 1

Just found out that if I'm addressing the PROD server via HTTP (HTTP listener with 'security' disabled, on a different port), it properly returns the whole message: `HTTP/1.1 400 LDAP credentials invalid!`.

So the problem only exists when accessing it via HTTPS (HTTP listener with 'security' enabled).

I'll dig further into that, playing with the 'security' switch.

### Update 2

Yes. Confirmed. When on PROD:

- using the Payara Admin Console
- navigating through Configurations -> server-config -> HTTP Service -> HTTP Listeners -> http-listener-1
- and there
- - a) flipping the 'Security' checkbox,
- - b) saving changes
- - c) restarting the Payara server
- - d) in the browser change address protocol from `https://` to `http://` or vice versa
- the behavior changes:
- - if security if OFF, the message gets sent completely (`400 LDAP credentials invalid!`)
- - if security is ON, only the numerical code gets sent: `400`

Now I'll check that same phenomenon on the community edition...

### Update 3

I have checked the behavior on the community edition: Community edition works as expected, both times returns the full message. Explicit:

- if security if OFF, the message gets sent completely (`400 LDAP credentials invalid!`)
- if security is ON,  the message ALSO gets sent completely (`400 LDAP credentials invalid!`)
  (I also tried swapping listener configs, also worked 100% fine)

Now I don't know if this related to the difference in versions,

- or if the old Enterprise Server also worked correctly, so it could be a newer version problem?
- or if the newer Community Server also has that (presumable) bug, so it could also be a newer version problem?

Will keep checking and update this question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Payara Server has a property named `sendError_1`, ... ,`sendError_N` that can be used to customize the response sent by the server when an error occurs. To configure the server to send only the HTTP status code, you can set the property value to an empty string. The setting could be applied to the virtual server in the `postbootasadmin` file or by creation of virtual server:

```
set "configs.config.server-config.http-service.virtual-server.server.property.send-error_1=code=400 path=/tmp/400.html reason="
set "configs.config.server-config.http-service.virtual-server.server.property.send-error_2=code=404 path=/tmp/404.html reason=NOT_FOUND"
```

The name of the virtual server in this example is *server*. By starting of the server it will be printed at the beginning of server log: `Created virtual server server`

But in your case, in production it could be simply reverse proxy that changes the requests.

Comment: Actually I want the message (`LDAP credentials invalid!`) from the code to pass through to the client. I'm afraid there is no reverse proxy removing the error message. I'll check out if the `postbootasadmin` is responsible for that problem.

Comment: Check if there is anything with `send-error_` in your domain.xml. The setting can be made from several locations but it will always be added to the resulting domain.xml. To be sure just `grep -R "send-error_" .` on the directory. There is only this one setting to override the errors on Payara/Glassfish.

Comment: Thanx for posting more infos. I had already removed all `send-error_` in any files, restarted the server multiple times, made sure `send-error_` would not re-appear anywhere (heavy config file generation in that environment). But even though it was gone everywhere, problem remained the same: server still only sent 400, and did NOT send `LDAP credentials invalid!` (I'm trying multiple status codes, none work).

To clear things up: my problem is not with the HTTP body, but with the actual HTTP status code response.